# DX12 Initialization Fail VS2019

Tags: c++, windows-10, directx, directx-12

I have done the init steps in DX10/11/12 many times before, all of a sudden in VS2019 DX12 will not create anything besides the following objects: `ID3D12Debug`, `ID3D12InfoQueue`, `ID3D12Device2`.

Even a straight creation of command queue fails:

```
    bool DX12ObjectFactory::CreateCommandQueue(ID3D12Device* pDevice, __out 
    ID3D12CommandQueue** ppCmdQueue, const D3D12_COMMAND_QUEUE_DESC& queueCreateDesc)
    {
        OnFailedThrow(pDevice->CreateCommandQueue(&queueCreateDesc, 
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&*ppCmdQueue)));
        return true;
    }
```

`HRESULT` message is:

> hr = 0x00000108 : An open/create operation completed while an oplock break is underway.

Error code lookup points to: `ERROR_TOO_MANY_POSTS 298 (0x12A)`

Weird thing is that things were working a few days ago, maybe a Windows update broke it...

Thanks

Comment: Tried rebooting? Updating graphics drivers? Closing background programs that might be using the GPU?

Comment: @AlanBirtles yes, one of the 1st things I did, also uninstalled Radeon 20.2.2 and reverted to 19.12.2, GPU is RX 580, and Ryzen 7 3700x, IDXGIAdapter1 enumeration picks primary GPU, in this case RX 580.

Comment: which windows 10 build/version do you use? which SDK build do you target?

Comment: Have you initialized all members of queueCreateDesc properly?

Comment: Try building and running one of the samples. You could also try instantiating my template and see if that initializes on your system. See [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates). Also, have you enabled the Debug Layer and looked for debug output?

Answer (score 1):

`D3D12_COMMAND_QUEUE_DESC` was initialized properly, issues seemed to be use of `IID_PPV_ARGS`, as it was fine with the old way of using `IID_ID3D12CommandQueue`, `(void**)&(*ppCmdQueue)`.

Also my swapchain issue I forgot to initialize buffer count with a value >= 2.